# How to use subroutine uniform in shader by GLFW

Tags: opengl, shader, subroutine, uniform

I successed by freeglut
How can I initialize it by glfw?
It's a new feature after OpenGL4.0.
here is my initialize code

after glfwInit():

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
```

and here is some of my shader code:

```
 subroutine vec4 ShaderVertType(); 
 subroutine uniform ShaderVertType DotModel;  

 subroutine(ShaderVertType) 

 vec4 ShaderForOBJ_Solid() 
 { 
  model_position = vec3(model_matrix*vPosition); 

 //vec4 trans_pos = normalize(vPosition)*0.5+0.5; 

 v_flight_space_pos = light_space_matrix*vec4(model_position,1.0f); 

 normal_trans_matrix = transpose(inverse(model_matrix));  

 //mat4 trans_matrix  = projection_matrix*view_matrix;

 T  = normalize(vec3(normal_trans_matrix*vec4(vTangent,1.0f)));
 //B = normalize(normal_trans3*vBiTangent);
 N  = normalize(vec3(normal_trans_matrix*vec4(vNormal,1.0f)));

 B  = normalize(vec3(normal_trans_matrix*vec4(vBiTangent,1.0f)));

 //T = normalize(-dot(N,T)*N);

 //B = cross(T,N);

 f_vNormal = normalize(vec3(normal_trans_matrix*vec4(vNormal,1.0f))); //normalize(vec3( inverse(transpose((model_matrix)))*normalize(texture(NormalMapData,trans_pos.xy).rgba))); 
 vec4 final_pos = projection_matrix*(view_matrix*(model_matrix*vPosition)); 
 return final_pos;  
 }
```

It can return a number that is not negative, but it does not work at the time it is set

```
glUseProgram(shaderManager->GetProgramHandle("mainShader"));
GLuint frag_index = glGetSubroutineIndex(CURRENT_PROGRAM, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "ShaderForOnlyTex");
GLuint ver_index = glGetSubroutineIndex(CURRENT_PROGRAM, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "ShaderForOBJ_Solid");
```

not work:

```
glUniformSubroutinesuiv(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, 1, &frag_index);
glUniformSubroutinesuiv(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1, &ver_index);
```

Comment: 1) Please stop using shader subroutines. It's a horrible feature. 2) Please provide a [mcve]; shader subroutine code is particularly fiddly, and your problem may be in code that you haven't presented.

Comment: Thanks,I've changed my shader,and stop using subroutines